# How to handle extended ascii characters in Java rest API

Tags: java, rest, api, encoding

I have Java APIs written using Java Jersey library. One of the POST API request accepts comments from the user which can be in multiple language. One of the language I want the API to handle is Czech. The API accept the comment in String but not all the characters are read/encoded properly for e.g. if the comment parameter sent to API request is - "comment":"ffáňčšď" but at the server end point not all the characters are encoded correctly i.e. the comment is received as "ffá??š?". I am using 'UTF-8' for the conversion and the Java version 1.8. So, how do I handle the encoding in order to receive the exact string sent as request parameter?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: is that in JSON?

Comment: Yes..it is in JSON

Comment: No, it's probably not. JSON *requires* that the payload is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: adding charset=utf-8 in the  header as 'application/json; charset=utf-8' fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding charset=utf-8 in the header as 'application/json; charset=utf-8' for key 'Content-Type' fixed the issue.

[image: Below image refers to the issue fix]

Answer (score 0):

Which tool are you using to calling the endpoint? I am assuming the application that you are using the call the endpoint is not using UTF-8 to decode the characters. If you are trying to call the endpoint from Postman and the default encoding in Postman is set to ASCII encoding, the string you are using will not be decoded properly by Postman because those special characters are not part of ASCII character set, which means it will replace those characters with '?'.